# How to click an specific TableRow within a TableLayout

Tags: android, xamarin.android, tablelayout, tablerow

I made my own compound control that display a data grid using TableLayout and adding programmatically Tablerows within a loop depending of the Array of Object that im binding to it and now i want to select an specific row with its specific data in order to be used by a method. So how can i select an specific row retrieving its data to delegate a method?

Comment: I have the same problem, but i want to use onItemClickListener on TableRow, because I want to know which column was pressed. Can't find the way how can convert TableRow into something witch supports onItemClick. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

hi you can try something like this,

```
 // create a new TableRow

    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setClickable(true);  //allows you to select a specific row

    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            System.out.println("Row clicked: " + v.getId());

           //get the data you need
           TableRow tablerow = (TableRow)v.getParent();
           TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(2);
           String result=sample.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

For more info refer [Android TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

Answer (score 8):

I tried Parth Doshi's answer and found it to be not quite correct. The `view` parameter in `onClick` is a `TableRow`, so  when `v.getParent()` is called, it returns a `TableLayout` object, and so an exception is thrown when casting it to `TableRow`. As such the code that works for me is:

```
tableRow.setClickable(true);  //allows you to select a specific row

tableRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        TableRow tablerow = (TableRow) view; 
        TextView sample = (TextView) tablerow.getChildAt(1);
        String result=sample.getText().toString();

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myActivity, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! that definitely works better than what was marked the answer