# OnItemClickListener use for TableRow

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, tablerow, onitemclicklistener

I want to know which column user pressed in one TableRow object. It is header of table and i want to set sorting of items by chosen column. 
I am able to use onClick listener in this case.
Problem is simmilar to [How to click an specific TableRow within a TableLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336117/how-to-click-an-specific-tablerow-within-a-tablelayout/31377918#31377918)

Comment: Do not make it more difficult.. Just set the onClickListener on each items that are added to your layout

Comment: I didn't think about it this way. Thank you i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

set Tag to each tablerow as follow:

```
tablerow.setTag(pass object of item which you want to set on this tablerow)
```

Now, set Listener:

```
tablerow.setListener(listener);
```

Listener should be pass from fragment/activity to Adapter.

So, when you click on any row, you will be able to listen it in fragment as:

```
listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.getTag(); here you will get object which you set above.
            }
        }
```

So, using the tag object, you can able to find which row it is.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using different layout for showing the data. GridView would be a nice solution. [GridView docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) There you should have the correct event, you are looking for [On item click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Comment: I know, but I am doing on bigger project and this would take more time than another solutions. But thanks