# get TableRow id

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I want to get `index` or `id` of clicked row in `TableLayout`. Some of the codes looks:

```
final TableRow rows = new TableRow(this);
rows.setClickable(true);
```

**Click action of the button, which adds rows to TableLayout**

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
row.setTag(String.valueOf(queue_number));
row.setClickable(true);

if (queue_number % 2 == 0) {
row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_grey));
} else {
row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}

TextView row_queue = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_queue.setText(String.valueOf(queue_number));
row_queue.setPadding(6, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_product_name = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_product_name.setText(product_name.getText().toString());
row_product_name.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_unit_of_measurement = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_unit_of_measurement.setText(unit_of_measurement.getText().toString());
row_unit_of_measurement.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_price = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_price.setText(price.getText().toString());
row_price.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_sum = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_sum.setText(sum.getText().toString());
row_sum.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

row.addView(row_queue);
row.addView(row_product_name);
row.addView(row_unit_of_measurement);
row.addView(row_price);
row.addView(row_sum);
root_table.addView(row);
queue_number++;
```

And in the click event of `rows` looks:

```
rows.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(v.getId()), LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                client_name.setText(String.valueOf(rows.getChildAt(1)));
//                   TableRow t = (TableRow) v.getParent();
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(t.getId()), LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                for (int id = 0; id < root_table.getChildCount(); id++) {
//                    if (v.getId() == id) {
//                        Toast.makeText(Satish.this, String.valueOf(r[0].getId()), LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    }
//                }
            }
        });
```

But this event returns just **nothing**. I don't know what's the wrong in my codes. I couldn't see mistake.

Any helpful comment/answer appreciated.

#### P.S I have searched out in the internet about this, but couldn't found the correct solution for this problem. But, maybe this question is possibly duplicate.

## Edit

I can replace field `rows` with `row`. If I do it there'll be **only one** `TableRow` element. So code looks like:

```
final TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
row.setClickable(true);
```

**Click action of the button, which adds rows to TableLayout**

```
row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
row.setTag(String.valueOf(queue_number));
row.setClickable(true);

if (queue_number % 2 == 0) {
row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_grey));
} else {
row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}

TextView row_queue = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_queue.setText(String.valueOf(queue_number));
row_queue.setPadding(6, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_product_name = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_product_name.setText(product_name.getText().toString());
row_product_name.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_unit_of_measurement = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_unit_of_measurement.setText(unit_of_measurement.getText().toString());
row_unit_of_measurement.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_price = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_price.setText(price.getText().toString());
row_price.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_sum = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_sum.setText(sum.getText().toString());
row_sum.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

row.addView(row_queue);
row.addView(row_product_name);
row.addView(row_unit_of_measurement);
row.addView(row_price);
row.addView(row_sum);
root_table.addView(row);
queue_number++;
```

In this situation some design problems occur in `TableLayout`.

Comment: that event returns "nothing" because the id of the row is not setted.

Comment: @juanhl as you see, I'm setting the `id` to each `row`. But how can I *set* the same id to the `rows` ?

Comment: Or how to write the `row` clickEvent in `onCreate()` method? I tried a lot of ways but no result...

Comment: sorry but, seeing your code I think that you never set the id for TableRow view. i see a setTag() maybe you want say that.

Comment: Oh, it's my sorry. Saying `row` I mean the `TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());`. Sorry for unclear speech.

Comment: the value of field queue_number is the index of the row?, if it is maybe you can use v.getTag() in your onClick() method

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336117/how-to-click-an-specific-tablerow-within-a-tablelayout

Comment: @juanhl result's same...

Comment: @AwaisKing yes, I visited given link, but again same result :/

Comment: Where do you use "rows" field?, I see "row", "rows" and "root_table" fields

Comment: I used "rows" only in "OnClickListener" method, field "row" I used in setting views to it (in button click action I wrote above). The "root_table" field used another place.

Comment: sorry but I can't understand what you are doing. How I see, there are 2 main elements, the TableLayout and its TableRows, if you want to add rows dinamically with a button, you will create there your TableRow with its own listener and add it to your TableLayout. Too you can set the id or the tag of that view for use it in the listener.

Comment: @juanhl I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the best solution for my problem.

I moved the following lines from *inside of* `onCreate()` to **button click event**:

```
final TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
row.setId(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(queue_number)));
row.setClickable(true);

if (queue_number % 2 == 0) {
    row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_grey));
} else {
    row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}

TextView row_queue = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_queue.setText(String.valueOf(queue_number));
row_queue.setPadding(6, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_product_name = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_product_name.setText(product_name.getText().toString());
row_product_name.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_unit_of_measurement = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_unit_of_measurement.setText(unit_of_measurement.getText().toString());
row_unit_of_measurement.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_price = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_price.setText(price.getText().toString());
row_price.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

TextView row_sum = new TextView(Satish.this);
row_sum.setText(sum.getText().toString());
row_sum.setPadding(0, 6, 0, 6);

row.addView(row_queue);
row.addView(row_product_name);
row.addView(row_unit_of_measurement);
row.addView(row_price);
row.addView(row_sum);

root_table.addView(row/*, queue_number*/);

// set onClickListener at runtime. This is working well for me.
root_table.getChildAt(queue_number).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) v;
        TextView num, p_n, u_o_m, p, s;
//        num = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
        p_n = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(1);
        u_o_m = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(2);
        p = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(3);
        s = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(4);
//        row_id = Integer.getInteger(num.getText().toString());
        product_name.setText(p_n.getText().toString());
        unit_of_measurement.setText(u_o_m.getText().toString());
        price.setText(p.getText().toString());
        sum.setText(s.getText().toString());
    }
});

queue_number++;
```